# Limitation of generics in C#2

Tags: c#, generics

I'm currently reading Jon skeet's amazing book "C# in depth (3d version)".
I'm stuck on p.99 dealing with lack of contravariance for generics.

```
class TestGenericVariance
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IComparer<IShape> x =new AreaComparer();
        List<Circle> circles = new List<Circle>();
        circles.Add(new Circle());
        circles.Add(new Circle());
        //The following line is invalid, Sort expects IComparer<Circle>
        circles.Sort(x);
    }

    public interface IShape
    {

    }

    public class Circle : IShape
    {

    }

    public class AreaComparer : IComparer<IShape>
    {
        public int Compare(IShape x, IShape y)
        {
            //No matter, just for the test
            return 0;
        }
    }   
}
```

This code is not working because Sort method expects

```
    IComparer<Circle>
```

as parameter type.

One of the work around suggested p.99 is to make AreaComparer class generic :

```
    class AreaComparer<T> : IComparer<T> where T : IShape
```

And then modify non-generic AreaComparer to derive from the generic one :

```
    class AreaComparer : AreaComparer<IShape>
```

In C#2, the code doesn't compile because Sort method on circles is still expecting an

```
    IComparer<Circle>
```

Am I missing something ?

Nota :If I change to :

```
    class AreaComparer : AreaComparer<Circle>
```

The first line of code in the main method asks form an explicit conversion

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Actually write the Compare() method.  Make it work both for a circle and a rectangle without using GetType().  And the problem gets to be a lot more obvious.

Comment: Will have a look when I get home and try to work out what I meant.

Comment: You heard it here folks...only Jon Skeet can figure out what Jon Skeet meant!

Comment: Better to leave it to Jon Skeet to interpret what Jon Skeet meant...

Comment: @HansPassant: In this case, the `IShape` interface *actually* has an `Area` property, which is missing in the code in the question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is that you make `AreaComparer` generic like this:

```
public class AreaComparer<T> : IComparer<T> where T : IShape
{
    public int Compare(T x, T y)
    {
        return x.Area.CompareTo(y.Area);
    }
}
```

Then when you need to sort, you construct a comparer with the correct type argument:

```
circles.Sort(new AreaComparer<Circle>());
```

Note that this is assuming that `IShape` has an `Area` property (as stated at the bottom of p97). That isn't in your sample code, and is required in order to implement the comparer sensibly.

The part about the non-generic derived class was only to simplify cases where you're happy with using `IShape` and don't want to keep repeating that.

Comment: Thank you guys (and especially Jon). Now I get it !